# PDF Kit View is not inside my Xcode Objects Library

Tags: xcode, pdfview

I'm currently using Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61), MacBook Pro (Late 2011) 10.13.6 High Sierra.

I want to add a PDF Kit View into my storyboard but it is just not listed inside the Objects Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDFView` is not listed inside the StoryBoard by default but you can just subclass a normal `UIView` class into `PDFView` inside the StoryBoard and make an outlet inside ViewController. Further, you would need to `import PDFKit` to make it work.

[Refer this for more info on implementation](https://medium.com/mindorks/rendering-pdf-documents-using-pdfkit-9ac4944a6dfb)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help! :)

I was not aware of this as this YouTube video shows the PDF Kit View inside the objects library: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4KER6AlfrU&t=304s

So I thought it had to be from the objects library in order to use it.

Comment: @user3573091 PDFView is in the object library for Mac, not iOS.